# PHP - Grouping Duration based events / rows into single html blocks

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I've got a bunch of 'events' in a table in which they have a start and an end column (both DATETIME). I'm fetching every event for a single day and somehow need to group them together so that they can be displayed as a single HTML block.

For example...

Row #1: Has a duration of 30 minutes, starts at 09:00:00 and ends at 09:30:00
Row #2: Has a duration of 30 minutes, starts at 09:30:00 and ends at 10:00:00
Row #3: Has a duration of 90 minutes, starts at 12:00:00 and ends at 13:30:00

What would be the best way to know that I need 2 html blocks... One that is a div that has a 60px height (for rows 1 and 2), and then because there's a break between 10:00:00 and 12:00:00 to have the another div that is 90px height (row 3).

Can this be done with MySQL somehow? Or do I have to do a PHP loop to check for empty spaces of time in order to know when I should close a div and begin a new one?

Any help would be beneficial.

This is more of a logic question than code question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL.  One way is using a correlated subquery to determine when "event periods" begin.  A new event period begins when it does not overlap with any others.  Then use this information to assign an "event period id" to each event.

Such a query would perform reasonably well with the right indexes.

You could do this in php.  I am biased toward putting such logic into the database rather than in application code.

Answer (score 0):

My personal bias is to keep formatting out of the database layer.  I would do this using PHP.

Assumptions based on the text of your question:

1. Duration is stored in the database
2. Duration increment = 30 minutes
3. Events do not overlap.
4. Duration data has been queried with ODBC
5. Duration query includes ORDER BY Start_Time
6. Duration data loaded into appropriate $result variables
7. Event blocks are 30px per event.

   ```
   $job_count = 0;

   $event_increment = 30;
   $event_height = 30;

   $this_block_height = 0;
   $this_block_content = "";


   while(odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
       //fetch all your results into arrays
       $duration[] = odbc_result($result, 1);
       $start_time[] = odbc_result($result, 2);
       $end_time[] = odbc_result($result,3);
       $event_count++;
   }

   for($x=0;$x < $event_count; $x++) {
       //loop through the arrays to format the blocks
       if($x + 1 == $job_count) {
           //if this is true, we are at the last element
           $this_block_height += $event_height; 
           $this_block_content .= $start_time[$x] . " to " . $end_time[$x] . PHP_EOL;
           echo "<DIV style='height:" . $this_block_height . "px;'>$this_block_content</DIV>";
       }
       else {
           if($end_time[$x] == $start_time[$x+1]) { 
               //if this is true there is no gap.
               $this_block_height += $event_height; 
               $this_block_content .= $start_time[$x] . " to " . $end_time[$x] . PHP_EOL;
           }
           else {
                //gap identified
                //write old block to file with padding on the end
                //reset values to start over
                $end_seconds = strtotime($end_time[$x]);
                $start_seconds = strtotime($start_time[$x+1]);
                $gap = $start_seconds - $end_seconds;
                $gap_minutes = $gap / 3600;
                $gap_increments = $gap_minutes / $event_increment;
                $this_block_height += ($event_height * $gap_increments);
                echo "<DIV style='height:" . $this_block_height . "px;'>$this_block_content</DIV>";
                //this will put the space padding at the end of the first block
                //instead of at the start of the second block  
                $this_block_height = 0;
                $this_block_content = "";
           }       
       }
   }
   ```